# Tick attendances in group meetings

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

There is one problem I cannot find an answer to. I am an experiences amateur vb programmer with SQL and Access experience. I have recently been asked to prepare a program to log Group Meetings attendances.

I have the following tables:

```
Members
    MemberID        AutoNumber
    GroupID         Number
    MemName         Text
    IsPresent       Y/N

Groups
    GroupID         Autonumber
    GroupName       Text

Meetings
     MeetingsID     Autonumber
     MeetingDate    Date
     GroupID        Number
     MemberID       Number
     AttendanceID   Number

Attendances
     AttendaceID    Autonumber
     MemberID       Number
     MeetingID      Number
     ISPResent      Y/N
```

I made my relationships...

```
MemberID in MemberTbl with MemberID in AttendTbl....
MeetingID in AttendanceTbl with MeetingID in MeetingTbl
MemberID in membersTbl with MemberID in LodgeTbl and 
LodgeID in LodgeTbl with LodgeID in MeetingsTbl
```

Each group has 1 meeting every month.

What I want is a way to list all members (in datasheet) that belong to a particular group with a checkbox depending if they were present at the particular meeting.

I have tried `AppendQueries` but that didn't work. I have really come to a dead end.

On the main form I have meetings as `RecordSource` with `GroupID` (user input). After update Sunform is updated and a list with all members belonging to the group appear with a tick box next to their names. The Child/Master link is by `GroupID`.

What I am trying to do is, in the list that appears in the subform I want to be able to tick persons present and their name to be logged in attendance tbl as present.

Comment: You can make your posts more readable by using the code button - `{}`

Comment: Why do you have both `GroupID` and `MemberID` in table `Meetings`?

Comment: You say *"Each group has 1 meeting every month."* So, the `MemberID` seems useless in the meetings table.

Comment: Is Meetings.MemberID the meeting owner?

Comment: If there is a record for every potential member in a group in the meetings table, the Attendance table is necessary only if it contains a record for those who actually attended (IsPresent can be removed as well.).

Answer (score 0):

if the record source for the main form is Meetings, you should use MeetingId as Master/Child link.

On the form, probably in AfterInsert event put some code to generate the attendance records for this Meeting.

```
currentdb.execute "INSERT INTO Attend ( MemberId, MeetingId ) SELECT Members.MemberId, Meetings.MeetingId FROM (Members INNER JOIN Groups ON Members.GroupId = Groups.GroupId) INNER JOIN Meetings ON Groups.GroupId = Meetings.GroupId WHERE (((Meetings.MeetingId)=" & me.MeetingId & "));"
```